# How to enable C autocomplete in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c, ide, autocomplete, codeblocks

How to enable C Std lib functions autocomplete in Code::Blocks?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Editor > Code-Completion and Symbols Browser and make sure Disable code-completion isn't checked.

Answer (score 0):

Code completion should include member functions autocomplete also. Where as I couldn't see it working. Suppose I want to access the member functions of stringstream class. It is not coming up automatically when I try to access it using the object of stringstream.

e.g,

stringstream str;
str. // nothing comes up automatically.

What needs to be configured ?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest code blocks 16.01 on windows 10, code completion for c didn't work when a new file was created and configured to be a c file.

However, when a new C project was created using (File/New/ Project/ Console Application), all declared functions and variables worked with the code completetion.

Hope this helps