# Modify Code Completion Settings in Code::Blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks, indentation, code-completion

I have a problem with Code::Blocks, is there a way to change the indent of the auto-completion for reserved words?

What I get:

`printf(|)
 scanf(|)`

What I want to get:

`printf(|);
 scanf(|);`

I want it to auto-add the **semi-colon** every time I type those reserved words.

for `|` being the location where the cursor will be.

Is it possible to edit the code-completion plugin?

Comment: This question has been _[asked, and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6749769/645128)_.  (_[related question/answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28422023/645128)_).  _[And here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3464900/645128)_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable C autocomplete in Code::Blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464900/how-to-enable-c-autocomplete-in-codeblocks)

Comment: @ryyker none of them solved my question... I need to **change** the way it works, there is no thing related to semi-colon, I need to edit the () to get the ();

Comment: The codeBlocks IDE is open source.  Either go to the user's forum and see what others are doing, or edit a copy of the IDE to match your specific expectations.

Comment: I just started my life as a programmer, and I know nothing about editing an IDE, all I need is how to auto complete with semi-colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still nothing about editing the code-completion, but I found another way to solve it, I used the

> Settings>Editor>Abbreviation

section to add the keywords to be able to `CTRL+J` and make the code with the semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

This is the official plugin site for Code Completion http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Code_Completion_plugin and this video may help you while setting it up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8ekpKgUIpM

Comment: Yeah... It didn't cover what I needed, I want to know a way to be able to auto indent the semi-colon whenever I type those reserved words (printf, scanf, others), I find it anywhere on the official website.